# interp is valid for monotonically increasing sample points?

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) for interp and it says

> One-dimensional linear interpolation for **monotonically increasing**
> sample points.

However, how about this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#x = np.arange(0, 3 * np.pi, 0.1)
#y = np.sin(x)

x = 3.6

#xp = [2, 4, 6]
#fp = [1, 3, 5]

#xp = [2, 4, 6, 8]
#fp = [1, 3, 5, 3]

xp = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
fp = [1, 3, 5, 3, 5 ]

xp = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
fp = [9, 7, 5, 3, 1 ]

xp = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 7]
fp = [9, 7, 5, 3, 1 , -2]

print(np.all(np.diff(xp) > 0))

gfg = np.interp(x, xp, fp)

print (gfg)
plt.plot(xp, fp)
plt.plot(x,gfg,'rp', markersize=14)
plt.show()
```

With this I get

[image: plot]

What is the explanation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking about the behaviour of `interp` in a regime where the documentation of `interp` doesn't make any claims about: The idea is that `np.interp` should only be used if the x-values of the sample points are monotonically increasing. Full stop. It doesn't make any claims of what happens if they are not monotonically increasing, I quote:

> The x-coordinate sequence is expected to be increasing, but this is not explicitly enforced. However, if the sequence xp is non-increasing, interpolation results are meaningless.

So maybe you're lucky and the interpolation worked, maybe not. In your case I imagine it might have worked because the x-values stop being increasing well after your query point, but this is not a behaviour you should rely on.